# Rails: How to send json response immediately for long running job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am processing long running jobs. i am invoking long running method from controller. i want to send json response immediately  to the user. below is my code but its not working.

```
def process
 p = Proces.new(:status => "in-progress")
 render :json => {:id => process.id}
 long_running_job()
end
```

How can i send json response immediately?

Comment: Which part isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: long_running_jobs() method runs for 20 minutes and after that i get json response. i want json response to be render immediately instead of waiting for 20 minutes

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your long_running_job in a background job queue. This will make your long running task occur outside of the web request cycle, allowing you to return the JSON immediately, while your long running processes continues elsewhere. Look into [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_job_basics.html) if you're on Rails 4.2+ and/or [Sidekiq](https://sidekiq.org/).

Comment: Whats even more important is that using a background process will free the web thread to accept other requests.